# Wcf Service Error The maximum message size quota

Tags: wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

I still get this error when ı am trying the call the webservice from console application. Thanks for any idea.

Here is my error details
**The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**

Here is my web.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="bBinding"  receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
              maxArrayLength="200000000"
              maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
          <!--https geldiği zaman, mod transport olmalı-->
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="srvBehavior">
          <!--https geldiği zaman httpsGetEnabled true olmalı-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="srvBehavior" name="FordDersService.FordDers">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bBinding" contract="FordDersService.IFordDers"/>
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wBinding" contract="FordDersService.IFordDers"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is your client config the same in terms of bind configurations?

Comment: Do ı need to modify client configuration. I add service using add service reference. And it automatically adds wcf service configurations into app config file.

Comment: @Polat, you should add same configuration on client config

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri thanx for reply. But ıt suppose to add this configuration automatically in app config?

Comment: It will add but with default settings. After this you have to manually edit it.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri you are right when ı changed the app config values it returns the data. But ıt is nonsense. When ı change the server config why ıt doesnt apply for the client?

Answer (score 0):

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>


          <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
                     maxBufferSize="20000000"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                     maxArrayLength="200000000"
                     maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: u need to add this config both wcf and mvc app